# Laravel 5.2 with GCM push notification

Tags: android, laravel, laravel-5, google-cloud-messaging, android-volley

I am trying to build a chat application.

I am using laravel 5 as back end and android device as my front end.

[I am following this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-push-notifications-using-gcm-php-mysql-realtime-chat-app-part-1/). They are using slim framework, But I am using laravel 5. I need to include GCM(Google Push Notification) into laravel so I am using this package [click here](https://github.com/davibennun/laravel-push-notification). But they have give a variable deviceToken. I don't know how they are generating and sending push notification.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The device token is generated with JavaScript. You have to ask the client in the browser if he/she allows you to send him/her notifications. If he/she clicks yes, a device token is generated. You have to send it via ajax to laravel and store it in the database. Then you can use it to send your notifications.

I would suggest you fcm instead of gcm. Both are from google, but the one from firebase seems to be the future one.

You can find a package here: https://github.com/brozot/Laravel-FCM

Comment: Is there any reference link for that? I have another question, Instaed of device token can we use user token?

Comment: You can go to firebase.google.com. there are also good videos on YouTube, just search for "firebase notifications". I don't think so with the token. Google needs to know to which browser it has to send the message. There is no database where browsers are connected to a user, but if you read the documentation I think you will understand it